# Why are the questions about Iran's nuclear threat against Israel off-topic

Tags: discussion, support, scope

Many questions about the Iranian Nuclear threat against Israel and the poor performance of the Biden administration have been closed as off-topic. (Israel itself is also to blame for not taking the Iranian nuclear threat seriously).
The Biden government's diplomacy is also foggy and has no clear future given the Iranian regime's secrecy.

But why off-topic?
Certainly during Trump's presidency, Iran's nuclear threat was weaker.

Anyway, I do not know how Iran's acquisition of a nuclear weapons can be taken offtopic.

[image: Example]

I asked [this question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/66733/did-trump-s-maximum-pressure-campaign-against-iran-fail-miserably) for example so that you can see how questions related to the Iranian nuclear threat are eliminated.

One of the comments clearly likes only the part related to criticizing Trump and wants to censor the part related to Biden!.

> it seems like an interesting question without the argumentative part linking US presidencies to Iran's alleged uranium enrichment rates

Comment: Can you provide any examples of such questions which were closed as off-topic? I remember closing quite a lot of such questions, but usually not because the subject is off-topic *per-se* but because they weren't actual questions. They were opinion pieces disguised as questions. But perhaps you are talking about some actual questions which were honest attempts to learn more about politics and political processes and not attempts to push a narrative or convince people of a political opinion? If so, please show them to us so we can take a closer look.

Comment: @Philipp The closed questions are not visible and referral, you as the admin are definitely aware of this.

Comment: *Deleted* questions are invisible to users with low reputation. *Closed* questions are visible to everyone. But deleted questions are still visible to high reputation users, so posting links to deleted questions can still help us to discuss them.

Comment: @ Philipp nope!, It is not  ```Page Not Found
This question was removed from Politics Stack Exchange for reasons of moderation. Please refer to the help center for possible explanations why a question might be removed```

Comment: High rep users can still see that question.

Comment: Again, since you seem not to understand, **questions are not for criticizing anyone**! There is no balance between the parts criticizing Biden and the parts criticizing Trump – neither should be criticized in a question. The point is to ask a question, not to argue a point. Any extraneous information should be removed

Comment: You might be interested to read that JJJ successfully asked the same question you did by phrasing it differently: "[Why is President Trump criticized for leaving the Iran Deal and his 'Maximum Pressure' campaign?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/66741/why-is-president-trump-criticized-for-leaving-the-iran-deal-and-his-maximum-pre)" As you can see, the problem with your question wasn't the topic, it was the style in which you wrote the question. You see, it is perfectly possible to ask questions about the JCPOA as long as you don't add accusations to your question.

Answer (score 10):

I'm not sure what questions you're talking about, but questions that are intended to promote or discredit are *explicitly* off-topic here. In fact, of the main close reasons on this site is:

> The primary purpose of this question appears to be to promote or discredit a specific political cause, group or politician. It does not appear to be a good-faith effort to learn more about governments, policies and political processes as defined in the help center.

From your question here, it's clear you want to use this site in order to make arguments blaming specific groups. See the direct quotes from your question above:

> poor performance of the Biden administration

> Israel itself is also to blame

> The Biden government's diplomacy is also foggy and has no clear future

This is not the site for what you want to do. Similar questions asking, essentially, "Why is Trump so bad?" were closed too for the same reason. If you want to rant about why Biden is the worst, feel free to do so on Facebook or Reddit, but on StackExchange, we have clear standards for what kinds of questions are on-topic on each site, and this is clearly not.

Comment: @F1Krazy If I were to ask a question now, why do they blame Trump, what do you think is the result?  Off-topic --Closed

Comment: @Monero Again, true or not, all of that is all irrelevant to the question of what is on-topic here. There is no "ban" on questions about Iran's nuclear program. If you look at the [[iran]](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iran) tag, you'll see dozens of well received questions. The problem is your posts are rants, not questions. This isn't the first time that you've spammed off-topic rants on this site. You need to ditch your oppression-fetish and take the time to learn what this site is for and what the rules are if you want to post here. Or, just go complain elsewhere

Comment: @divibisan  Honestly, all good questions are closed. Even in your link.

Comment: I can right now ask a question and you will see what the result will be

Comment: @Monero Then perhaps this isn't the right site for you. When you come into a community, you need to follow that community's rules and culture. If you're looking for a site where you can freely rant about Biden and Israel etc., there are plenty of other places on the internet for that. But not here – this is a site intended for objectively answerable, unbiased (as much as possible) questions and answers. Please read the [tour] and decide if this is the right site for you

Comment: [Does Trump’s Maximum Pressure Campaign Failed Miserably?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/66733/does-trump-s-maximum-pressure-campaign-failed-miserably) As I promised.

Comment: @divibisan  I have never insulted (or rant) and I have evidence for everything I said

Comment: @divibisan   The problem is here, they really do not want what you said (for objectively answerable, unbiased), I mean the Democrats. And I'm not a Republican or a Trump supporter.

Comment: @Monero most people here seem to believe you did rant, as evidenced by the downvotes on this question, the close votes on your other questions on the main site, and the delete votes on your questions on the main site.

Answer (score 6):

The original text of the question read as follows:

> An official from the Biden government's negotiating team has recently
> claimed:
>
> > Trump’s Maximum Pressure Campaign Failed Miserably*. -- Robert Malley.
>
> During whose presidency did Iran increase its uranium enrichment rate
> from 20% to 60%? Obviously Biden.
>
> By what measure did Trump's stance on Iran fail?

The problem I see with this question is that it *appears* clearly and heavily slanted against the Biden administration (I say 'appears' because that may not have been your intention). If I were to paraphrase what you wrote it would be something like:

> A Biden official said something bad about a Trump policy when
> **clearly** Biden's policy is worse. Why would he do that?

The use of an embedded rhetorical question in particular makes the whole question sound pushy, as though it's implying that the Biden official is outright lying. And the last question comes off almost as though you are daring people to prove you wrong. Politics SE excludes both heavily loaded questions and questions meant to confirm a worldview or belief, so you can see why this might have been received poorly.

If you wanted to write a more neutral question, you'd want something like the following:

> Under the Biden administration, Iran's uranium enrichment rate rose
> from 20% to 60%, and yet Robert Malley claimed that Trump's policies
> towards Iran failed miserably. What are the differences between
> Biden's and Trump's approaches, and how should we evaluate them?

That might still fail as asking for too much speculation, but at least you're not importing untoward presumptions, such as the presumption that Iran's increased production implies that it is producing more (or any) *weapons grade* uranium.